# Discover 100 T nitrox shock absorbers replacement with other modals/ brands

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, shock-absorber, bajaj

I have a Bajaj Discover 100T with nitrox shock absorbers. The nitrox shock absorbers are not working and I need to replace them with a Bajaj or other brand but not with the current Discover 100T OEM shock absorbers.

Can someone suggest which models of nitrox shock absorbers are compatible with the Bajaj Discover 100T.

Thank you.

Comment: It is better/recommended to stick with OEM parts. I'm not sure what's compatible with Bajaj Discover. By the way, what do you mean when you say that the suspension isn't working?